# How to protect every API endpoints by API key in header 'x-api-key' in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-authorization

I wrote an authorization middleware for API key in ASP.NET Core. My goal is to secure all API endpoints so that they require a valid API key in the `'x-api-key'` header. My problem is, that when I am not sure how to use it right.

I don't know if I am missing something or should I add more code. The token is empty (returns 401 code).

Example of using it:

```
[HttpGet]
[ApiKeyAuthorization]
[Route("subgroups/{parentId}")]
public IActionResult GetSubgroups(int parentId)
{
    // some code...
}
```

The code behind:

```
public class ApiKeyMiddleware
{
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ApiKeyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _next = next;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var apiKey = context.Request.Headers["x-api-key"].FirstOrDefault();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiKey) && _configuration["AllowedApiKeys"]!.Contains(apiKey))
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401; // Unauthorized
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized");
            }
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class ApiKeyAuthorizationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration? _configuration;

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var apiKey = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["x-api-key"].FirstOrDefault();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiKey) || !IsApiKeyValid(apiKey))
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }

        private bool IsApiKeyValid(string apiKey)
        {
            var allowedApiKeys = _configuration.GetSection("AllowedApiKeys").Get<string[]>();
            return allowedApiKeys.Contains(apiKey);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The most common process here is just build your API, and don't worry about it at this level. Instead, you publish the actual API solution so it's only reachable via a private network. Then there are existing products that will do this for you which you can purchase. They act a reverse proxy, and will pre-authorize the header, including enforcing rate limits, before allowing the request to proceed to the actual endpoint via the private channel. This also lets you handle load balancing and reporting without muddying the code doing the actual work.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn  I understand it, in spite of this,  It is something thath I have to use as I have described it.

Comment: Look into adding an authorization policy when you call `AddAuthorization`. I would apply `[Authorize(Policy = "HasValidApiKeyHeader")]` to anything I want protected by the API key, and define a policy by that name with a handler that checks the API key requirement.  It sounds more involved than what you have here, but it's a lot more modular and actually fits into the authorization system.

Comment: @madreflection Ok, that sounds better, could you provide me please some easy example to show it?

Comment: Start with [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies). If you don't have an understanding of the system first, you're going to have a hard time maintaining it.

Comment: There are dozens of blog posts about it. Some are better than others. The one that helped me had a really nice diagram showing the relationship between handlers and requirements, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow my steps to implement this function.

**My Project Structure**

[image]

**ApiKeyMiddleware.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public class ApiKeyMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ApiKeyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _next = next;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var apiKey = context.Request.Headers["x-api-key"].FirstOrDefault();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiKey) && _configuration.GetSection("AllowedApiKeys").Get<string[]>()!.Contains(apiKey))
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401; // Unauthorized
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized");
            }
        }
    }
    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class ApiKeyMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseApiKeyMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

**ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public class ApiKeyAuthenticationSchemeOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
    {
        public string? ApiKey { get; set; }
    }
    public class ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<ApiKeyAuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        //TODO Change to whatever name you want to use
        private const string ApiKeyHeaderName = "x-api-key";

        public ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler(
           IOptionsMonitor<ApiKeyAuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
           ILoggerFactory logger,
           UrlEncoder encoder,
           ISystemClock clock,
           IConfiguration configuration)
           : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey(ApiKeyHeaderName))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Header was not found"));
            }

            string token = Request.Headers[ApiKeyHeaderName].ToString();


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) || !IsApiKeyValid(token))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Token is invalid"));
            }
            else {
                Claim[] claims = new[] {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "jason p"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "jasonp***@gmail.com"),
                };

                ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, nameof(ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler));
                AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), Scheme.Name);

                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
            }
            
        }
        private bool IsApiKeyValid(string apiKey)
        {
            var allowedApiKeys = _configuration.GetSection("AllowedApiKeys").Get<string[]>();
            return allowedApiKeys.Contains(apiKey);
        }
    }
}
```

**Add `AddAuthentication` and use the apikey middleware in Program.cs file.**

```
namespace WebApplication5
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication("ApiKey").AddScheme<ApiKeyAuthenticationSchemeOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>("ApiKey",opts => opts.ApiKey = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AllowedApiKeys")
            );
            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseApiKeyMiddleware();

            app.UseAuthorization();


            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**My appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AllowedApiKeys": ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
}
```

And we can use `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "ApiKey")]` to protect the api controller.

[image]

**Test Result**

Use the wrong key `aa` first, then use the correct one `aaa` later to check it.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the example! If I am understand it right, the important is implement `ApiKeyAuthenticationSchemeOptions` ?